# deploying react app in git workflow with updating base path as repo name

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

deploying to `gh-pages` using workflow having base url issue. actually my `dist` folder deployed under `https://3gwebtrain.github.io/Ultimate-React-23/` git path with `repo` name. but after the deployment, my app searching the files from `https://3gwebtrain.github.io/` that means without including my `repo` name. so my pages are blank.

please check here: `https://3gwebtrain.github.io/Ultimate-React-23/`
Is there a way to git deployment to know the correct directory to fetch the files from updating the workflow?

here is my current workflow:

```
name: React Build

on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']

env:
  CI: false

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'
      pages: 'write'
      actions: 'write'
      checks: 'write'
      deployments: 'write'
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Build
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build

      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v2
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
        with:
          # Upload build directory content
          path: 'dist/'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

as a simple I would like to navigate the assets from
`https://3gwebtrain.github.io/assets/index-cef14fe5.js` in to
`https://3gwebtrain.github.io/Ultimate-React-23/assets/index-cef14fe5.js`

Comment: Are you sure anything got uploaded? See https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact#customization-if-no-files-are-found. Also it seems like you could simplify the workflow substantially by knowing which package manager you're using already.

Comment: Now you've completely changed the question. Fundamentally how you fix this depends what you're actually using to build the app, e.g. for CRA see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not using  `gh-pages` writing my own workflow.

Comment: That's totally irrelevant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I am not get you. what is irrelevant? can't we deploy using our own workflow?

Comment: How specifically you're getting the bundled files up to where they're served by GitHub Pages (or even whether they _are_ served by GHP, for that matter) is irrelevant when the problem is that those bundled files are not correctly configured to be served at a subdirectory.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, May I can have a comment or suggestion for the same.  But requesting a help how would be a irrelevant?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I don't think you are either, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using the base name with `BrowserRouter`

```js
<BrowserRouter basename={import.meta.env.BASE_URL}>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path='product' element={<Product />} />
    <Route path='pricing' element={<Pricing />} />
    <Route path='app' element={<AppLayout />} />
    <Route path='*' element={<Pagenotfound />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```